# get text from stdout in subprocess.run without UnicodeDecodeError

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess

I read the output from a windows command line call like so:

```py
result = subprocess.run(["cmd", "/c", "dir","c:\mypath"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, text=True,check=True)
```

The result may contain unexpected characters and I get a UnicodeDecodeError. It tried to sanitize it with `text = result.stdout.encode('ascii','replace').decode('ascii')` but this doesn't always help.

How do I robustly read the text avoiding any UnicodeDecodeError?

Comment: God kills a kitten every time you remove non-ASCII characters just because you don't know what to do with them. Before you proceed, finally read Joel Spolsky's [_The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excluses!)_](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you cannot rely on the subprocess to produce valid text, don't use `text=True`; but then the onus is on you to try to figure out the encoding when you need to decode the value.

```
result = subprocess.run(
    ["cmd", "/c", "dir", r"c:\mypath"],
    capture_output=True, check=True)
print(result.stdout.decode("cp1252"))  # or whatever encoding the system is using
```

If you can predict the expected encoding, you can also say

```
result = subprocess.run(
    ["cmd", "/c", "dir", r"c:\mypath"],
    capture_output=True, check=True, encoding="cp1252")
```

By the looks of it, you are on Windows; probably examine your current system encoding (what's the output of `chcp` in a CMD window?) and adjust accordingly.

(Notice also the use of a raw string for any string value with a literal backslash in it.)

And of course, to merely get a directory listing, probably prefer `os.scandir()` or its `pathlib` equivalent.

Comment: `["cmd", "/c", "dir","c:\mypath"]` is only a placeholder; in reality I call a more complex command line tool.

Comment: with CP437 I can reliably process the output

Comment: Incidentally, for finding the correct encoding for a piece of 8-bit text, perhaps (the generic) you will want to try https://tripleee.github.io/8bit/